# Javascript in XSL that is loaded by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

Is there anyway to have javascript run when a XSL sheet has been applied to an XML file by Javascript?

I am using a JQuery plugin to apply the sheet to the xml but the javascript that is located inside of the XSL file will not run.

I put the Javascript at the bottom of the file and it still does not run.. I can't seem to get an alert to even run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.glyphix.com/

This will load the XSL for you and run all Javascript for you. It will not include the new dependencies the file may have but if you include them in the top HTML file you will nto have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where (and how' do you place the output of the XSLT transformation?
Have you tried eval´ing the javascript block after the transformation?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to wait until after the HTML is put into my object so I can even evaluate it..